# php username check on database when user already taken

Tags: php, forms

Hi i have a registration system, and it works well and save to database, I have a problem in checking on the database for the username if already exists. My script on checking database is wrong. Can someone help me on this? Below is my code

```
<?php  
   if(empty($_POST['username'])){
          $username_error = "Please Input Username";
        }else{
          if( 6 > mb_strlen($_POST['username']) || 20 < mb_strlen($_POST['username'])){
            $username_error = "username must be at least 6 characters.";
          }else{
            $sql = "SELECT
                    members.username
                    FROM
                    members
                    WHERE username = $username";
              $res = mysql_query($sql);
              if(mysql_num_rows($res)){
                $username_exists = "Username is already taken.";
              }else{
                $username = $_POST['username'];
              }
          }     
        }
?>
```

problem is only in the else statement

Comment: You're prone to SQL injection.

Comment: There's no connection - in the code you've just posted (stop changing your code. Now it doesn't reflect our answers and won't help anyone else.) - to the database.

Comment: i post that code coz its only on that lines of code having problem only the check on database

Comment: its only in the else statement to check if username exists on the datbase

Comment: thats very very understandable code ive posted im looking for a corect answer that checks the database! thats it!

Comment: Your query will fail as you're not treating `$username` as a string. [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21551697/3000179)

Comment: others are posting a wrong answer! i dont understand why they post like that

Comment: can you help me modify my code???

Comment: Only if you go about this properly, and don't alter your OPs code three times so that answers posted don't reflect your code anymore, and if you are willing to "use the fishing rod, and not just expect fish to come to you"

Comment: @h This was clearly a hand-holding "Debug my code" question that won't ever help anyone else which makes it inappropriate for SO. I don't know what you expected. Don't encourage it.

Answer (score 1):

Change :

```
 $sql = "SELECT
                    members.username
                    FROM
                    members
                    WHERE username = $username";
```

To:

```
 $sql = "SELECT
                    members.username
                    FROM
                    members
                    WHERE username = '".mysql_real_escape_string($username)."'";
$users =mysql_query($sql);
if(mysql_num_rows($users )){
   $username_exists = "Username is already taken.";
}{
   $username = $_POST['username'];
}
```

Have in mind, you need to escape your user name to avoid SQL injection! And avoid using **mysql_** functions!

Comment: No , it's not! I added the single quote and escaping!

Answer (score 0):

```
if(mysql_num_rows($sql)>0){
          $username_exists = "Username is already taken.";
        }else{
          $username = $_POST['username'];
        }
```

Although you should be using PDO or something else for sanitization.

**Correction:**

```
        $res = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
        if(mysql_num_rows($res)){
          $username_exists = "Username is already taken.";
        }else{
          $username = $_POST['username'];
        }
```

Comment: hi where will i add this code? below mysql_query($sql) right?

Comment: `$sql`  is string and can't be used by `mysql_num_rows` function!

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @undone . I have updated the code to show the correct part. Cant believe how i missed that! >_< lol

Comment: i tried this got ang error
Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\TheSocioNet\stud_reg.php on line 209

Comment: I've added "or die(mysql_error())" to the end of the query part. This will tell you the reason why.

Comment: now this is the error
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 5

Answer (score 0):

**Before you read on**; this is prone to SQL injection, and I'd love to point you to [PDO](https://www.php.net/pdo).

Change your SQL statement to treat `$username` as a string;

```
SELECT members.username
FROM members
WHERE username = '$username'
```

Then remove the following line,

```
mysql_query($sql);
```

And finally change your `if() { }` condition to;

```
if(mysql_num_rows(mysql_query($sql))>0){
```

Comment: ahh okay i get it ill try this

Comment: why remove the mysql_query($sql);

Comment: Either assign `mysql_query($sql)` to a variable to then do a `mysql_num_rows` check, or remove it and move onto step 3.

Comment: ahh okay i see ill try

Comment: Grab the value of `$username` and run it manually (in a mysql interface; ie. phpMyAdmin). Are you sure that the value of `$username` doesn't already exist in `members`?

Comment: yes i already grab the value of the $username and im sure i try inputting a data without the same name in table members

Comment: can you modify my code above?? inside the else statement

Comment: please help this wont work can you modify mo code above?

Comment: The logic here is correct. Please update your OP with your database table data, and your tests.

Comment: OP = Original post(er). I can modify your code, but I have no idea what's already in your database table (data wise) or the tests you've done.

Comment: i added my whole code now.. i edit it above my problem if the user register the username and that username is already taken in the database it validates username already taken

Comment: hey i know you guys can solve my prblem but why you posted wrong answers??? feels me confusing anymore

Comment: did you understand my question?

Answer (score 0):

```
var qc=document.forms["regform"]["email"].value;
if(qc!='') {
 alert('in');
 $.ajax({
        url: 'search.php',

        data: "check_qc=" + qc,
        async:false,
        success: function(response) {
            if(response==1)
            {
                alert('Already Exists');
                return false;
            }

        }
    });
}
```

Now, in search.php file

```
$qc = $_GET['check_qc'];
$sel="select * from register where email='".$qc."'";  
       $res=  mysql_query($sel);             
       $co=  mysql_num_rows($res);             
      // echo $co;      


    if(count($co)>0)
        echo "1";
    else
        echo "0";
```

Comment: yes because in search file we just chk into databse that email id exists or not. if it exits then it returns 1 else 0. this response we recevie in our main file like this if(response==1)
            {
                alert('Already Exists');
                return false;
            }

Comment: no you posted a wrong answer! instead check the database with the username only in php not javascript

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to help you with this code. Pay attention to comments. I have done more then just, answer your question: there are a bit changed logic, added sanitize of $username...

```
<?php

// at first let's define this variables (just for any case)
$username_error = null;
$username_exists = null;

// get username
$username = $_POST['username'];

// let's check it
if (empty($username)) {
    $username_error = "Please Input Username";

    // don't know in what context you use this code
    // so here you need to return from function or exit
    return;
}

// ... and sanitize
$username = filter_var($username, FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS); // just for example
// actually, I use active record, so can't suggest 100%-security way

// check lenght
if (mb_strlen($username) < 6 || mb_strlen($username) > 20) {
    $username_error = "username must be at least 6 characters.";

    // also let's exit or return
    return;
}

// and now let's check it in DB
$sql = "SELECT
        members.username
        FROM
        members
        WHERE username = '$username'";

// !!! pay attention!!!
$result = mysql_query($sql); // we need append this mysql result to some variable

if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) { // and here we check num_rows of that result, not just tring with query!
  $username_exists = "Username is already taken.";

  // also let's exit or return
  return;
}

// if we are in here we have sanitized $username, that's not in use.
// Enjoy!
```

Comment: @billycrogan, please, try to change "return;" on "exit('lalala');" with different "lalala" :) and look, what it output, in such way we will see, where is the problem