# php username that checks on database "username already taken"

Tags: php, mysql, forms

Hi i have a registration system, And it works well, my problem is that how will i check the username if already taken based on my database ?? i have this script and it wont work, can someone help me solve this??

```
<?php

        if(empty($_POST['username'])){
          $username_error = "Please Input Username";
        }else{
          if( 6 > mb_strlen($_POST['username']) || 20 < mb_strlen($_POST['username'])){
            $username_error = "username must be at least 6 characters.";
          }else{
              $username = $_POST['username'];
              $sql = "SELECT
                    members.username
                    FROM
                    members
                    WHERE username = $username";
              $res = mysql_query($sql);
              if(mysql_num_rows($res)){
                $username_exists = "Username is already taken.";
              }else{
                $username = $_POST['username'];
              }
          }     
        }


?
```

the problem is on the else statement check the database if username is taken.
Please help me out on this , many thanks

i get this error

`Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\TheSocioNet\stud_reg.php on line 210`

Comment: `mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());`

Comment: try WHERE username = '$username'

Comment: Do use the deprecated `mysql_*` functions, and **definitely** don't build SQL by putting POST variables into it.

Comment: No connection to the database in the code posted. Have you *successfully* connected to the database?

Comment: This code is very insecure and suffer from SQL Injection. You can use addslashes to have a bit of security but you should definitely check the prepared statements for MYSQL PDO

Comment: mysql_query returns false if the result is empty. So you'd write if(!$res){// username doesn't exist}. Also, make sure to use mysql_real_escape_string on the $username. And - Rikesh is right… you're not assigning $_POST['username'] to $username

Comment: its there #username = $_POST['username'];

Comment: yes ive put a connection on database its on above not posted in here

Comment: yes i tried to query on phpmyadmin it works

Comment: You still haven't replied to @Rikesh. Does it give you any error?

Comment: Don't help a vampire/troll http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21551581/php-username-check-on-database-when-user-already-taken/21551697#comment32549244_21551697

Comment: user007 no its not working your code @Rikesh

Comment: What error was displayed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use below code to fix your problem

```
<?php

    if(empty($_POST['username'])){
      $username_error = "Please Input Username";
    }else{
      if( 6 > mb_strlen($_POST['username']) || 20 < mb_strlen($_POST['username'])){
        $username_error = "username must be at least 6 characters.";
      }else{
          $username = $_POST['username'];
          $sql = "SELECT
                members.username
                FROM
                members
                WHERE username = '". $username."'";
          $res = mysql_query($sql);
          if($res && mysql_num_rows($res) > 0){
            $username_exists = "Username is already taken.";
          }else{
            $username = $_POST['username'];
          }
      }     
    }
```

?

Comment: That will fail. `$username` should be treated as a string in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: no it wont validates your code

Comment: its not working i tried it it does not validated to username is taken

Comment: dammn!! this one is correct!! this is what im looking for your WHERE username = $username is lack of '$username' single quote above!

Comment: I have updated the code, please use and let me know if you still facing the same issue

Comment: i thanks it works now only here you forgot WHERE username = '". $username."'"

Comment: many thanks men! your the only one who got my answer correct!

Comment: Really Billy? And what part of my answer on your other question didn't tell you that? http://stackoverflow.com/a/21551697/3000179

Comment: yes this part wont work on your answer
if(mysql_num_rows(mysql_query($sql))>0){

Comment: oh sorry @h i forgot to put this above the sql $username = $_POST['username'];

Comment: @h you forgot to add that $usernam = $_POST['username']; on your sql code above